# PHP accessing an SplDoublyLinkedList cross function

Tags: php, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I am working with php and I have run into a predicament. I need my doubly linked list to be accessible cross function. What I have been doing in order to solve this is passing down the address of the variable explicitly in the parameters. Is this approach a valid solution? It looks similar to this:

```
function foo(&$list){
    $list->push('a');
    $list->push('b');
    $list->push('c');
    $list->push('d');

    $list->setIteratorMode(SplDoublyLinkedList::IT_MODE_FIFO);
    for ($list->rewind(); $list->valid(); $list->next()) {
        echo $list->current()."\n";
    }
}
```

Also, on a side note, am I able to store an object in the linked list by simply doing the following?

```
function foo(&$list){
    //assuming Pie is a class with a method get_pie_flavor()
    $myBar = new Pie('cherry');
    $list->push($myBar);

    $list->setIteratorMode(SplDoublyLinkedList::IT_MODE_FIFO);
    for ($list->rewind(); $list->valid(); $list->next()) {
        echo $list->current()->get_pie_flavor();
    //will this print 'cherry' assuming get_pie_flavor is written correctly?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the side note: Yes you can do exactly that.  Also the pass by reference does work exactly as depicted above assuming the list is initialized correctly.